# Why doesn't the complexity of hashing and BSTs factor in the time required to process the bytes of the keys?

Tags: data-structures, hash, big-o, binary-search-tree, time-complexity

I have a basic question on the time complexity of basic operations when using hash tables as opposed to binary search trees (or balanced ones).

In basic algorithm courses, which is unfortunately the only type I have studies, I  learned that ideally, the time complexity of look-up/insert using **Hashtables** is O(1). For **binary (search) trees**, it is O(log(n)) where "n" is the "number" of input objects. So far, hashtable is the winner (I guess) in terms of asymptotic access time.

Now take "**n**" as the size of the data structure array, and "**m**" as the number of distinct input objects (values) to be stored in the DS.

For me, there is an ambiguity in the time complexity of data structure operations (e.g., lookup). Is it really possible to do Hashing with a "calculation/evaluation" complexity constant time in "**n**"? Specifically, if we know we have "**m**" distinct values for the objects which are being stored, then can the hash function still run faster than "Omega (log(**m**))"? 
If not, then I would claim that the complexity for nontrivial applications has to be O( log ( **n** ) ) since in practice "**n**" and "**m**" are not drastically different.

I can't see a way such function can be found. For example, take **m**= 2^O( **k**) be the total number of distinct strings of length "**k**" bytes. A hash function has to go over all "**k**" bytes and even if it takes only constant time to do the calculations for each byte, then the overall time needed to hash the input is Omega( **k** ) = Omega( log( **m**) ).

Having said that, for cases where the number of potential inputs is comparable to the size of the table, e.g., "**m**" is almost equal to "**n**", the hashing complexity does not look like constant time to me.

Comment: I think that in practice, *n* and *m* *are* often drastically different. It's not unusual to have a 64-bit key, but a hash table with 2^64 values is impossible.

Comment: Just because two objects have the same value doesn't mean they will have the same hash values. Consider the scenario where an object's hash value is the address it's stored at.

Comment: @mattnedrich - If you define equal as same value, the hashes absolutely should be equal too! This is exactly the contract set for hashes in Java (and I assume other languages). In your example, where an object's hash is its address, 2 objects with different address should *not* be considered equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is valid, though I think there's a secondary point you're missing. If you factor in the time required to look through all the bytes of the input into the calculation of the time complexity of a BST, you would take the existing O(log n) time and multiply it by the time required for each comparison, which would be O(log m). You'd then get O(log n log m) time for searches in a BST.

Typically, the time complexities states for BSTs and hash tables are not the real time complexities, but the number of "elementary operations" on the underlying data types. For example, a hash table does, on expectation, O(1) hashes and comparisons of the underlying data types. A BST will do O(log n) comparisons of the underlying data types. If those comparisons or hashes don't take time O(1), then the time required to do the lookups won't be O(1) (for hash tables) or O(log n) (for BSTs).

In some cases, we make assumptions about how the machine works that let us conveniently ignore the time required to process the bits of the input. For example, suppose that we're hashing numbers between 0 and 2<sup>k</sup>. If we assume that we have a [transdichotomous machine model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model), then by assumption each machine word will be at least Ω(k) bits and we can perform operations on machine words in time O(1). This means that we can perform hashes on k bits in time O(1) rather than time O(k), since we're assuming that the word size grows as a function of the problem set.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this indeed helped a lot. I noticed the O(log(n)^2) complexity of BST when considering bit-level operations but again, if we could do optimization at that level, we might end up with not comparing the full key at each child since when traversing to some node, we already have some common information about the size of the input and the next node. BTW, thanks for the link to transdichotomous machines. (low reputation, will come back later to vote up :))

Comment: @user2372040: The common prefix assumption won't reduce the complexity of the comparisons, because convergence to a common prefix is linear. Suppose that the elements have `k` bits; we then expect `k` comparisons and we expect the common prefix on the `ith` comparison to be `i` bits long. The time for all comparisons is then `k(k+1)/2` which is still `O(k^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fair point. If your container's keys are arbitrarily large objects, you need a different analysis. However, in the end the result will be roughly the same.

In classic algorithmic analysis, we usually just assume that certain operations (like incrementing a counter, or comparing two values) take constant time, and that certain objects (like integers) occupy constant space. These two assumptions go hand in hand, because when we say that an algorithm is `O(f(N))`, the `n` refers to "the 'size' of the problem", and if individual components of the problem have non-constant size, then the total size of the problem will have an additional non-constant multiplier.

More importantly, we generally make the assumption that we can index a contiguous array in constant time; this is the so-called "RAM" or "von Neumann" model, and it underlies most computational analysis in the last four decades or so (see [here](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/11/history-of-ram.html) for a potted history).

For simple problems, like binary addition, it really doesn't matter whether we count the size of the objects as `1 object` or `k bits`. In either case, the cost of doing a set of additions of size `n` is `O(n)`, whether we're counting objects-of-a-constant-size or bits in variable-size-objects. By the same token, the cost of a hash-table lookup consists of:

1. Compute the hash (time proportional to key size)
2. Find the hash bucket (assumed to be constant time since the hash is a fixed size)
3. Compare the target with each object in the bucket (time proportional to key size, assuming that the bucket length is constant)

Similarly, we usually analyze the cost of a binary search by counting comparisons. If each object takes constant space, and each comparison takes constant time, then we can say that a problem of size `N` (which is `n` objects multiplied by some constant) can be solved with a binary search tree in `log n` comparisons. Again, the comparisons might take non-constant time, but then the problem size will also be multiplied by the same constant.

There is a lengthy discussion on a similar issue (sorting) in the comments in [this blog post](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/05/shaving-logs-with-unit-cost.html), also from the Computational Complexity blog, which you might well enjoy if you're looking for something beyond the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. I will check the blog. I guess the task of finding complexity, at least in theory, relies on the definition of elementary operations. However, my concern was for scenarios where the input is an "array" of some length "k" and more importantly, when "k = log(n)". For those keys I did not find it easy to come up with an heuristic on how the hashing should be performed.

Comment: @user2372040: The (stochastic) `O(1)` time-complexity of a hash table relies on the (average) bucket size (or chain length) being a constant size. If the array is expected to be dense in the domain of possible values (so that `k = O(log n)` using your symbology), then the range of the hash function must have a size which is `O(n)`. In other words, the length of the resulting hash must be `O(k)`, typically `k` minus a small constant. This doesn't affect the cost of computing the hash, but it might cast doubt on the RAM assumption that indexing by the hash is possible in constant time.